# How to create partitions in Tkinter like these?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[This is the kind of GUI that I what to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD2KP.png)
I thought this is the PannedWindow, but I don't know how to do that. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `ttk.Labelframe`.

See http://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com/2012/07/tkinter-labelframe-demo.html

Comment: tkinter itself also has a `LabelFrame` widget.

Comment: Worked. Perfect. Thank you. Another small query. Can the OptionMenu in Tkinter be made to look like something other that what the default is?

Comment: Like all tkinter widgets you can set the [background, foreground, etc.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/iwidgets3.0/optionmenu.n.html)